# Scaling a field value within the result set

Tags: solr, solr4

I am using the scale function in order to normalize the values of a field between 1 and 3. The problem is that the values are not normalized relative to the result set, but to all the indexed documents.

For example:

```
/select?q=id:173540413&fl=id,scale(id, 1, 2) 
id,"scale(id, 1, 2)"
173540413,1.9903924

/select?q=id:(173540413 173540377)&fl=id,scale(id, 1, 2) 
id,"scale(id, 1, 2)"
173540413,1.9903924
173540377,1.9903922
```

The desired result would be:

```
/select?q=id:173540413&fl=id,scale(id, 1, 2) 
id,"scale(id, 1, 2)"
173540413,1

/select?q=id:(173540413 173540377)&fl=id,scale(id, 1, 2) 
id,"scale(id, 1, 2)"
173540413,2
173540377,1
```

Is there some other way to scale the results, perhaps without using scale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a roundabout way to achieve this in Solr.

Solr's scaling function behaves differently when used against a field that is **query dependent** vs when used against a field that is **not**.

So when you are trying to scale a field like **'id'** that is not query dependent, Solr considers the entire document set to scale. This will alter your min and max to be taken from the entire doc-set instead of the query result set. Whereas, when you scale a query dependent value like **query($q)** (which is the **TF-IDF** text similarity score for a document against the searchterm), Solr considers only the search result set to get the min and max for scaling.

Now, what we want is the second option. So, we do something like this:

q=searchterm&fl=id,**scale(sub(sum(id,query($q)),query($q)), 1, 2)**

This is what we're doing with the field: id + query($q) - query($q)

This tricks Solr into thinking that this is a query dependent field, when in fact it evaluates to the same 'id' field. This will give you a smooth **[1,2] range based scaling** as intended.

Apart from **scale()**, I believe this approach will also work with **other function queries** like **max()** and **min()** which operate on entire document set instead of just the query result set.

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna try this ASAP. I hope it isn't a big performance hit.

Comment: It seems to work with 6.4.0 but not with 4.8.1. Anyhow, thanks for the ingenious approach. I marked this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Stats Component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component) to get the min/max values for your set, then do the scaling yourself in your middleware.

The element below `stats / stats_fields / fieldname` should have a `min` and `max` key that indicates the extremities of values in your query result.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that. I have to use those values as a boost.